# Right to Left (Hebrew) support in IntelliJ Community Edition

Tags: intellij-idea, right-to-left

Is there a plugin or an easy way to write right to left in IntelliJ Community Edition?
Maybe a hack that developers are using?
I'm writing an Hebrew android application and it's really hard to write the resources files.

Comment: `editor.new.rendering=true` in `idea.properties` file as of IntelliJ 15.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steps to solve this are apparently made for Idea 15, Currently (August 2015) in early access.

See this comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5810#comment=27-1015891
You need to add the line `editor.new.rendering=true` to your `idea.properties` file for it to work.

I just tested it, and it seems to be working pretty well, but it is an early access.

Answer (score 3):

I'm facing the same problem here, I'm trying to write Persian apps in intellij and it's really annoying!

I kind of use a hack to solve the problem. I edit everything in intellij except string.xml file. I edit this file with other editors that have no problems with with rtl languages. It's not the perfect solution but its a lot better!
I use bracket IDE. It is a very simple IDE for developing web apps and it works with rtl languages as well.

Answer (score 2):

Editing of RTL languages is not supported ATM (and no estimations on when it will be) -- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5810

Comment: @Benny This needs to be implemented on the low level (Editor itself) -- I do not see how some plugin can help here.